# How to report on "persistent" separate segments in GA4 e.g. internal vs external traffic (can't just create new Views anymore)

Tags: google-analytics

My use case is as follows:

I need to create some kind of different "reporting profiles" if you will for **internal** (staff) vs. **external** (everyone else) traffic (in this case I am using a user-scope custom dimension to differentiate the two traffic types).

In the old days (Universal Analytics) I would create the following **Views**:

1. *All traffic* (totally unfiltered)
2. *Main* (All/combined traffic, but may contain certain broad filters like anti-spam)
3. *External Traffic* (filters the Internal users)
4. *Internal Traffic* (filters the External users)

99% of the time, everyone would use the "External" View; it would have exactly what we expect to see in it, and the data would obviously be applied to *all reports*. But if we want to see other/combined traffic, easy-peasy, just select it from the top and you're good to go.

Now I have no idea how to handle this fundamental requirement in GA4!

I need to make it easy for regular users to find and use, and persistent/applying to all reports.

What's the analagous way to manage this need? Thanks.